How to shows subtotal with Js addEventListener?
When the add button is clicked, the subtotal value is updated and the result of price * quantity is displayed but, it doesn't work.
`
<body>

<section class="section dashboard">
  <form action="http://127.0.0.1:4321/pembelian/add/create" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="zwlU7e6su5TVTxRAWZiXnMMdMFDrVZtk5WATlXWT" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="col text-end mb-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="submitButton" fdprocessedid="fh7vd">Buat Pesanan</button>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="image-container" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; background-color: white; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
            <img src="http://127.0.0.1:4321/assets/images/storage/../eskrim.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="storage/../eskrim.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; object-fit: contain;">
          </div>
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h5 class="card-title">Es Krim</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Rp 12.500</p>
            <p class="card-text">13</p>
            <div class="flex flex-col gap-0 items-center">
              <input type="hidden" name="produkId[1]" value="1" id="produkId1">
              <div class="flex flex-row gap-0 items-center justify-center w-full">
                  <button type="button" id="button-min1" class="border-0 focus:outline-none" fdprocessedid="g7pore">-</button>

                  <input class="input-quantity border-0 bg-transparent focus:outline-none focus:ring-0" type="number" name="total_produk[1]" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="quantity1" fdprocessedid="wlgdxd">
                  
                  <button type="button" id="button-plus1" class="border-0 font-semibold focus:outline-none" fdprocessedid="rkul0jd">+</button>
              </div>
                  
                  <div class="flex flex-row w-full">
                    <span class="border-0">Subtotal : Rp</span>
                    <input id="subTotal1" value="0" type="text" class="border-0 text-sm text-start bg-transparent" disabled="" fdprocessedid="b4zjhr">
                  </div>
                </div>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <script>
            var minOp = document.getElementById('button-min1');
            var plusOp = document.getElementById('button-plus1');
            var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity1');
            var subTotal = document.getElementById('subTotal1');
            var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

            minOp.addEventListener('click', function() {
              var value = parseInt(quantity1.value);
              if (!isNaN(value) && value > 0) {
                quantity1.value = value - 1;
              }
              calcSubtotal1()
            })

            plusOp.addEventListener('click', function() {
              var value = parseInt(quantity1.value);
              if (!isNaN(value))
                quantity1.value = value + 1;

              calcSubtotal1()
              console.log('value', value);
            })

            function calcSubtotal1() {
              var price = 12500.00;
              var quantity = parseInt(quantity1.value);
              var subTotals = price * quantity;
              subTotal1.value = number_format(subTotals, 0,',','.');

              console.log('subTotal1.value', subTotal1.value);
            };

            

            function number_format (number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
                // Strip all characters but numerical ones.
                number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
                var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
                    prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
                    sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
                    dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
                    s = '',
                    toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
                        var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
                        return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
                    };
                // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
                s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
                if (s[0].length > 3) {
                    s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
                }
                if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
                    s[1] = s[1] || '';
                    s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
                }
                return s.join(dec);
            }
</body>

I did change the value to 1, and when clicking the plus button, it changed to 0. I also checked console.log('value', value) and console.log('subTotal', Subtotal), the data came in but the subtotal didn't change at all.
I've also asked chat gpt, but the results don't show any progress.
Can anyone help me?

Things to check/try: 1. Any javascript errors in the browser's console? 2. Right-click on the page, and click view page source to see if the values are as expected in the javascript code. 3. Depending on the browser (in Firefox there is a Debugger tab, in Chrome it's called Sources), you can set break points on the javascript code for step-through debugging to see the handling. Set a breakpoint on the last statement in the calcSubtotal function, click an Add button, and then you can step into the number_format function. As you step along, you can hover the variables to see their values.

We don't have your data or your laravel setup available, so please show an example of the rendered HTML, instead of the template code.

@PaulT. 1. No, there's no error in browser console, when i run console.log ('value', value) (for the items add) and ('subTotal' Subtotal) for subtotal, the data and logic is run. The value is fine, but it didn't show up in browser (html)

@CBroe I'm sorry before, should i add a picture of the website? Or what I should I put?

No, not a picture, but the actual HTML code that results from your template. ("View source" in your browser, and then copy&paste the relevant section from there.)

Perhaps I'm wrong about this, but - your JS variables and functions are within a foreach, and they seem to be constantly overwritten by the next instance in the loop. Also, are there any instances where your #produkId{{$item->ProductID}} is occurring more than once in your rendered HTML? As in - you have multiple individual instances of one specific product (e.g. instead of 5 apples, you have 1 apple, 1 apple, 1 apple, etc).

Oh, I'm sorry. I already add the html rendered @CBroe.

Yes you're right, the JS are in foreach. No, in html rendering it doesn't appear one by one. But the problem is that the subTotal doesn't appear in the browser @FiddlingAway

Missing a closing  tag in what's shown above, but other than that, it appears to work? https://jsfiddle.net/1bqL3p42/

The program is run as expected. There's something wrong with number_format function. So I use this What is the JS equivalent to the PHP function number_format?
Thank you for your attention.
